# Lock row for read and update - only 1 process should update a row at a time

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have been asked to check a production issue for which I need help. I am trying to understand the isolation levels and different locks available in SQL server.

---

I have a table `JOB_STATUS` having columns `job_name (string, primary key), job_status (string), is_job_locked (string)`

Sample data as below:

| job_name | job_status | is_job_locked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JOB_A | INACTIVE | N |
| JOB_B | RUNNING | N |
| JOB_C | SUCCEEDED | N |
| JOB_D | RUNNING | N |
| JOB_E | INACTIVE | N |

Multiple processes can update the table at the same time by calling a stored procedure and passing the `job_name` as input parameter. It is fine if two different rows are getting updated by separate processes at the same time.

BUT, two processes should not update the same row at the same time.

Sample update query is as follows:

```
update JOB_STATUS set is_job_locked='Y' where job_name='JOB_A' and is_job_locked='N';
```

Here if two processes are updating the same row, then one process should wait for the other one to complete. Also, if the `is_job_locked` column value is changed to `Y` by one process, then the other process should not update it again (which my update statement should handle if locking is proper).

So how can I do this row level locking and make sure the update query reads the latest data from the row before making an update using a stored procedure.

Also, would like to get the return value whether the update query updated the row or it did not as per the condition, so that I can use this value in my further application flow.

Comment: To determine if the row was updated or not, assign `@@ROWCOUNT` to a local variable and subsequently check for zero or one.

Comment: What you're doing is data twiddling, not row-level locking. Row-level locking uses transactions, and `WITH (ROWLOCK)` hints on the table being updated, to maintain exclusive access to that row (or group of rows) for the duration of the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE: "Here if two processes are updating the same row, then one process should wait for the other one to complete. "

That is how locking works in SQL Server.  An UPDATE takes an exclusive lock on the row -- where "exclusive" means the English meaning of the word: the UPDATE process has excluded (locked out) all other processes while it is running.  The other processes now wait for the UPDATE to complete. This includes READ processes for transaction isolation levels READ COMMITTED and above. When the UPDATE lock is released, then the next statement can access the value.

IF what you are looking for is that 2 processes cannot change the same row in a single table at the same time, then SQL Server does that for you out of the box and you do not need to add your own "is_job_locked" column.

However, typically an is_job_locked column is used to control access beyond a single table.  For example, it may be used to prevent a second process from starting a job that is already running.  Process A would mark is_job_locked, then start the job.  Process B would check the flag before trying to start the job.

Answer (score 0):

I did not had to use explicit lock or provide any isolation level as it was a single update query in the stored procedure.

At a time SQL server is only allowing one process to update a row which is then read committed by second process and not updated again.

Also, I used `@@ROWCOUNT` to get the No. of rows updated. My issue is solved now.

Thanks for the answers and comments.